# IdentityServer4 ASP.NET Core Identity does not redirect back to client

Tags: c#, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I have basic IdentityServer4 with Asp.Net Core Identity. After redirecting to the login page and signing in, IdentityServer does not redirect me back to the client.

IdentiyServer Config:

```
 new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientName = "MVC Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:50309/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:50309/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }
```

IdentityServer Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddDefaultUI();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
        {
            iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
            iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        });

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
        })
            .AddSigningCredential("CN=tst")
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        //app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

MVC Client Startup:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        //JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("api1");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

There is a warning in the console, but all the URLs are correct `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.`

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what *does* happen? As in, what's the browser displaying instead of redirecting?

Comment: @KirkLarkin After filling in a valid email and password, click on the "Login" button and login. But I stay on the sign-up page and nothing else happens. Here is the output from the console:
`https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjecY1mAQaKShpU-11yR5k0_Go6ZBg`

Comment: @Michal, were you able to resolve this?  I'm getting the same response in my sample app.

Comment: @terryt unfortunately not, I used their example template

Comment: authorization_code grant should still work. It is just hard to understand why redirect does not work using ASPNET Identity login but redirect works in the IS4 TestUser login.

Answer (score 2):

From your code, please change the **http to https** identityserver works on https only
RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:50309/signin-oidc" },

PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:50309/signout-callback-oidc" },

and also in your MVC client you need to change that too.
  options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";

Comment: This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, and something that I had been searching for all day. Thanks!

Comment: Yes i also believe , Documentation need to improve right now its very hard to follow

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here is the problem:

https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/301

You are setting https redirection in your code but you did not specify any port.

Try adding configuration or removing

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Comment: After configuring or removing `app.UseHttpsRedirection ();` warning disappeared, but redirect still does not work.

Comment: Are you performing redirect anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Redirect where and when?

Comment: I'm going to the client URL. I'm not logged in, I'll be redirected to IdentityServer. I log in and IdentityServer must redirect me back. This works in an example where I do not use Asp.Net Identity. It must work the same way with it. Where should I make a manual redirect?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with the redirect after sign-in. In my case, I removed the SSL endpoint in my IdentityServer project's launchsettings.json. IMO it should be okay to not use SSL when testing locally. This is what caused the issue for me though. Adding the SSL endpoint back resolved the issue.

i.e.

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "SelfHost": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001"
    },
    "<YOUR-PROJECT-NAME>": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001"
    }
  }
}
```

I also had to update the issuerUri in the `Startup` class to

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer(options => 
{
    options.IssuerUri = "https://localhost:5001"
});
```

I couldn't find any info on this in the docs either. I spent hours trying to resolve this issue, there are no errors in the logs when this happens, even with verbose logging configured you can't trace what's causing it.